# ODBC Driver / FreeTDS

Tags: php, sql, linux, odbc, freetds

I am migrating a PHP website that connects to an external MSSQL database. The new server is a Linux server. I know to get this to work I will need an ODBC driver for Linux, like these:

- FreeTDS
- Microsoft's ODBC driver for Linux.

My question is, do I need both or can I get this to work with just one of them?

Comment: I've found FreeTDS to be more reliable than the Microsoft driver, particularly with multi threading. Which flavor of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You will only need one ODBC driver, which might be one of those you list, or might come from another source such as [those from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sqlserver/).

The ODBC driver must match bitness with your PHP binary (whether that's the standalone executable, `mod_php` as used with Apache, or otherwise), and you'll generally be best off if you also have an ODBC driver manager (e.g., [iODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/), [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/)).

If you get pre-built binaries for any of these components, note that they must be compatible with the `libc` in your environment, which may mean that you need to add a compatibility library (for instance, binaries built for `libc 2.5` need a compatibility library to be used in a `libc 2.12` environment).